# REST API returning model undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a simple table that contains a varchar field called `typename`. It's defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE public.ref_community_types
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('ref_community_types_id_seq'::regclass),
  typename character varying,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT ref_community_types_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I want to run a simple GET for all rows from that table through my REST API but I'm getting this 500 error:

```
  RefCommunityType Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "ref_community_types".* FROM "ref_community_types"
  Rendered ref_community_types/_ref_community_type.json.jbuilder (48.6ms)
  Rendered ref_community_types/index.json.jbuilder (68.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 204ms (ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `type' for #<RefCommunityType:0x00000007068270>):
    1: json.extract! ref_community_type, :id, :type, :created_at, :updated_at
    2: json.url ref_community_type_url(ref_community_type, format: :json)

app/views/ref_community_types/_ref_community_type.json.jbuilder:1:in `_app_views_ref_community_types__ref_community_type_json_jbuilder__1812723856_58877260'
app/views/ref_community_types/index.json.jbuilder:1:in `_app_views_ref_community_types_index_json_jbuilder__546876462_59109520'
```

My browser returns the following:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/ref_community_types
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
```

I've looked at all the typical spots that might cause this (`routes.rb`, `models/ref_community_type.rb`, `controllers/ref_community_types_controller.rb`, `migrate/[date]_create_ref_community_types.rb`) but they all contain the name `typename`.

Where else can I look? I'm doing a search against the term "type" but it's pretty generic and my search results are returning a lot of unrelated results.

Comment: It looks like `_ref_community_type.json.jbuilder` is trying to call `type` on `RefCommunityType`. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app/views/ref_community_types/_ref_community_type.json.jbuilder` and change `type` to `typename`